# How to restart level if user checkoffs 3 missed days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, model-view-controller, model, integer

I'm creating an app where Users track their positive habits.

To make tracking positive habits more fun I broke it down into levels, specifically 5 levels.

Each level has a certain amount of `:committed` days associated with it (`case n_days`).

If a User checks off the box 3x in the _form `<%= f.check_box :missedone %>` than level one should restart. How can we make this work for `:missedone`, `:missedtwo`, `:missedthree`, `:missedfour`, `:missedfive`?

`:committed` days are those days a User said he would do the positive habit.

For example, I am `:committed` to running Mon - Fri. Missed would therefore only be checked off if I missed a day Mon - Fri.

```
class Habit < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    before_save :set_level
    acts_as_taggable
    serialize :committed, Array

  def self.comitted_for_today
    today_name = Date::DAYNAMES[Date.today.wday].downcase
    ids = all.select { |h| h.committed.include? today_name }.map(&:id)
    where(id: ids)
  end

    def levels
            committed_wdays = committed.map { |day| Date::DAYNAMES.index(day.titleize) }
            n_days = ((date_started.to_date)..Date.today).count { |date| committed_wdays.include? date.wday }

  case n_days     
      when 0..9
        1
      when 10..24
        2
      when 25..44
        3
      when 45..69
        4
      when 70..99
        5
      else
        "Mastery"
        end
    end

private
    def set_level
     self.level = levels
    end 
end
```

**habits/_form.html.erb**

```
  <label> Missed: </label>
  <div>
  <label> Level 1: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missedone %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedone %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedone %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 2: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missedtwo %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedtwo %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedtwo %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 3: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missedthree %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedthree %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedthree %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 4: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missedfour %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedfour %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedfour %>
  </div>
  <div>
  <label> Level 5: </label>
  <%= f.check_box :missedfive %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedfive %>
  <%= f.check_box :missedfive %>
  </div>
```

**habits_controller.rb**

```
    class HabitsController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_habit, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
      before_action :logged_in_user, only: [:create, :destroy]

      def index
        if params[:tag]
          @habits = Habit.tagged_with(params[:tag])
        else
          @habits = Habit.all.order("date_started DESC")
          @habits = current_user.habits
        end
      end

    private

        def habit_params
          params.require(:habit).permit(:missedone, :missedtwo, :missedthree, :missedfour, :missedfive, :left, :level, :date_started, :trigger, :target, :positive, :negative, :tag_list, :committed => [])
        end
    end
```

**_create_habits.rb**

```
class CreateHabits < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :habits do |t|
      t.integer :missedone
      t.integer :missedtwo
      t.integer :missedthree
      t.integer :missedfour
      t.integer :missedfive
      t.integer :level #broken down via n_days
      t.text :committed
      t.datetime :date_started
      t.string :trigger
      t.string :target
      t.string :positive
      t.string :negative
      t.references :user, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :habits, :users
    add_index :habits, [:user_id, :created_at]
  end
end
```

I've been killing myself trying to figure out this answer so any help would be GREATLY GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say that, but i don's see the point of doing it that way. You will end up with state related logic inside your models (in fact it's what you have right now, and what's causes all problems).

Anyway, to answer your question, the first thing is that you're doing it wrong (in my opinion anyway). To make it work you have to start again few things.

I would go with [state_machine](https://github.com/pluginaweek/state_machine) gem in your case. That way you can free your self from state transitions logic. You'll have to map those in your classes, but it will be way more readable and maintainable this way.

Using state machine you're probably could map different states for your habits, like `level0`, [...], `level5` and `master` and then just define transition conditions.

For example let's say you have a `committed_count` and `missed_count` fields in you model.

---

Condition to go from `level0` to `level1` would be:

`committed_count > level1_go_up_const`

Condition to go from `level1` to `level0` would be:

`missed_count` > level1_go_down_const`

---

And so on for other levels. And yes, you should extract those numbers as constants, or even better as variables (so user could customize it in settings.

On every change your habit should try to degrade it's state. If that's not possible (not enough missed days) then it tries to advance it's state. If that's not possible (not enough committed days) than nothing state-related happens. If that's possible on the other hand, then it advances in state. And every state change should change committed and missed values to zero so the next / previous state can track it's own limits and behave adequate to that.

This way you can - when the basics will work - add some sugar on top of that without doing some `magic` unreadable (for anybody else) operations, switch/cases and mystic if statements, and so to make other things you will or need right now - like checking past days as missed if they are not checked as committed neither as missed, or adding some sort of week-schedule for certain activity type (probably it should be editable by user). And so on.

To make this happen you should also consider to introduce more small and meaningful private methods because in near future you wont remember what's going on.